# Can't create page from template in subdirectory of site root

Tags: dreamweaver

So I've got my template file in templates/template.dwt. It works just fine for all the file that are in the site root (one directory above the templates folder) but whenever I try to create a page from the template and save it in a subdirectory, say 'pooh', it won't update the links. Everything links as if it's in the root (so all the links in non-editable regions are broken).

Can you save a page from a template in a subdirectory of the site root?

God I really hate dreamweaver but no alternative as the site is hundreds of html files ... what a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the links in my template file weren't properly set.... if the links in the template file are not accurate, do not expect links in pages created from that template file to work!

Answer (score -1):

I found this out the hard way, after investing hours of creating templates and nested templates, that when I work with a subdirectory and move files to the server, they are all linked incorrectly and they are broken. There is no option to not link them to the root directory so I had to make them all over again. In DW CC 2017, I can't save a template without DW freezing, and DW crashes often working with templates. Dreamweaver is like an abusive boyfriend. A bad crutch. We know to learn other apps now.